# GameCenter Leaderboard will not update after release

Tags: ios, swift, game-center, gamekit

GameCenter has been working fine before release when updating the high scores. Now, it has been over 24 hours and the highscores will not update at all. Instead, it only shows my score in "Today" and does not share it with anyone nor can I see anyone else's score although they have played the game.

Prior to the release it worked fine.

Here is what I have done,

**Enabled GameCenter in Xcode**

[image]

**Created the Leaderboard in iTunes Connect**

[image]

**Enabled Leaderboard for App**

[image]

**Added correct methods to authenticate player & show leaderboard**

[image]

**Added correct methods to send scores**

[image]

It all worked in the app prior to launch and updated scores to everyone. Now it just updates scores for that one person with their own score.

I have even deleted my own scores within iTunes Connect and it will not update on any devices and just keeps the score prior to deleting.

**This is the Today section even after many people played**

[image]

**This is how All Time looks, it has not updated once since release**

[image]

There are multiple questions like this but are not recent and deal with the sandbox (which was eliminated) and everything seems correct

Is there a crucial step I am missing? Are Apple's servers down? Does it just take very long for new apps to update leaderboards?

Comment: One suggestion: check the status of the error in your authentication handler. The common pattern found on the internet is to assume that a nil ViewController means you're successfully logged in. However, when the error is set, the VC will also be nil. I always check the if error is nil before evaluating the VC. Berfore digging deeper, I would check if there's a clue hiding in that error message.

Comment: @Thunk I had printed out the error and it was nil. Not really sure what is going on here, everything seems right in the code and there are no errors at all.

Comment: I'm betting it's on Apple's side. Yesterday, the developer portal was down. Today, after I posted that comment, I found that I'm not getting any cloudkit push notifications anymore.

Comment: Hopefully. I do not want to have to release another version just because of of a stupid mistake. I am contacting iTunes Connect support and will let you know what the issue was (hopefully it is on there end so it is a quick fix for them)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone else who had this issue, I contacted iTunes Connect support and they went to their engineers. Apparently they were able to do something and have the scores sync correctly to iTunes connect.

It took 3 days but now there scores are all correct